# Handling null properties within props used to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a simple edit component in which the object to be edited is assigned as a prop of the component.

For example:

```
export default {
  name: "EditPersonModal",
  props: {
    person: {},
  }
  ...
}
```

A `person` object contains an `address` object, which in turn contains `city`, `state`, `zip`, etc.

Within the component, it is not possible to model the address fields wth `v-model="person.address.city"` as `person.address` is null.

One solution to this is to check `person.address` on creation, and set to `{}` if it is undefined, however this results in the empty property making its way to the back-end. Obviously, I could check for this, and null the property prior to any further processing but is there a cleaner was of doing this that doesn't involve checking each of a child object fields?

The same issue is also faced on an **Add component**

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea about vue but maybe JavaScript's optional chaining operator works there too? `v-model="person.address?.city"`.

Comment: In Vue, we can't bind the `prop` directly to `v-model`. So, you need to preprocess your `prop` anyway.

Comment: @TrietDoan I am already assigning the `prop` to `v-model` without issue. If the prop did not have properties that were objects, this would work as intended. Can you clerify what you mean by we can't find the `prop` directly to `v-model`?

Answer (score 4):

Like @TrietDoan commented, you should avoid mutating props directly in child component. Instead of `v-model`, just use `:value` and then use optional chaining:

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
      <textarea :value="person.address?.city ?? ''" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"></textarea>
  `,
  props: {
    person: {},
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      item: {name: 'pers', address: {city: 'city'}},
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateCity(city) {
      this.item.address.city = city
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <p>{{ item.address.city }}</p>
  <Child :person="item" @input="updateCity" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. 1 question: How would the data in the city field eventually make its way into an object that can be POSTed to backend, as well as any non visible fields on the `person` such as ID that are used to update?

Comment: Hey mate, you can listen to event from child `<Child :person="item" @input="some method in parent" />`

Comment: I see. It would be great to not lose ability to model the inputs, as there are dozens. I've considered a data `person` which is cloned from the prop, but it still lacks the address field that is modeled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use optional chaining:

`v-model="person.address?.city ?? ''"`

`person.address?.city` mean that if `person.address` is `null` or `undefined` it return `null`.

The `??` operator return the result on the right if the left-hand operator is `null`

Comment: Vue complains that this is not a valid LHS. :/

Comment: It's unfortunate because someone might want to dynamically allocate entity input fields. E.g. `v-model="entity.translated[fieldName]"`..